# Program crashes at NSString to NSDate conversion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a nice little for-loop and I am stuck. I am afraid I've gone code blind, or is it object blind? I can't tell... My app crashes on the line marked `-->` and I can't see why.

```
    for(int search = 2; search<10; search=search+2) {
    NSString *arrayTime = [searchArray objectAtIndex:search];
    arrayTime = [@" " stringByAppendingString:arrayTime];
    NSString *arrayDate = [currentDate stringByAppendingString: arrayTime];
    --> NSDate *compareTime = [wholeDateTimeFormat dateFromString: arrayDate];
    NSDate *searchCompareTime = [wholeDateTimeFormat dateFromString:searchTime];
    NSLog(@"Start: %@ --- search: %@", compareTime, searchCompareTime);
    float compareResult = [searchCompareTime timeIntervalSinceDate: compareTime];
    NSLog(@"compareReslut: %f", compareResult);     
}
```

Some explanations: `currentDate` is formatted like this: `@"yyyy-MM-dd"`.
And `wholeDateTimeFormat` is formatted like this: `@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"`.

Then I need to convert it to an NSDate object; this is where is fails, and I have no idea why as of now. I blame it on the fact that I am falling ill. :)
I have no build errors and still it dies on me. Why? :D I am grateful for all the help I can get.

Comment: What is `wholeDateTimeFormat`?

Comment: What do you mean "it just dies"?  What's the error?

Answer (score 4):

Just use NSDateFormatter - it does all this automatically!

(I was going to try to be more specific - but your code has me a bit confused).

Anyway - something like:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease]; 
[df setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"]; 
NSDate* date = [df dateFromString:@"2010-11-02"];

NSLog(@"Converted date is %@",date);
```

Comment: @Jeremy P: Yes it just dies. And it says: [NSCFString dateFromString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a240c0'

Comment: Brad: If you look at my code, I admit that the code view here is that good, or it is my code that makes it bad. However I do exactly as you say I should. This is the line it crashes on: NSDate *compareTime = [wholeDateTimeFormat dateFromString: arrayDate]; I know that arrayDate is a NSString, as declared on the line above. wholeDateTimeFormat is declared outside the for-loop is that it?

Comment: What is "wholeDateTimeFormat", and what is the crash?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved.
The problem was outside the scope of this code and as I suspected I had become code blind.
I got a friend to watch the code and it took him 2 secs to spot the problem.

I released the dateformatters before the for-loop.

Thanks for all the input!